# Ubuntu Download for BeagleBoard-xM

Tags: beagleboard

Can you please tell me which version of Ubuntu is best for BeagleBoard-xM and where can I download it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the site http://www.armhf.com for my pre-built images for a simpler BeagleBone Black and you might start there since the instructions are very simple and easy to follow. I don't have the xM hardware to test the 12.04-precise or 13.10-saucy images so there's no guarantee everything would work.

You could look at the pre-built images from http://www.elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Saucy_13.10 which was updated in mid December 2013 for your exact hardware if you prefer the instructions there and a more sure chance the image will support your BeagleBoard-xM.